# How to convert WrappedArray to String using Spark / JAVA

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have the following dataframe :

```
+--------------------+
|    column          |
+--------------------+
| [99896, 10, ]      |     
|[50, 30, 40, ]      |
+--------------------+
```

Shema of column is :

```
 |-- column: array (nullable = true)
    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

When I execute the following code :

```
for (Iterator<Row> iter = dataframee.toLocalIterator(); iter.hasNext();){
        String item = (iter.next()).get(0).toString();
        System.out.println(item);
    }
```

I get the following output :

```
WrappedArray(99896, 10, )
WrappedArray(50, 30, 40, )
```

How can I convert this output to String like :

```
[99896, 10,50,30,40 ]
```

I need your help .

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

### Load the test data provided

```java
  Dataset<Row> df = spark.sql("select column from values array(99896, 10, null), array(50, 30, 40, null) T(column)");
        df.show(false);
        df.printSchema();
        /**
         * +-------------+
         * |column       |
         * +-------------+
         * |[99896, 10,] |
         * |[50, 30, 40,]|
         * +-------------+
         *
         * root
         *  |-- column: array (nullable = false)
         *  |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
         */
```

### Option-1

```java
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[");
        for (java.util.Iterator<Row> iter = df.toLocalIterator(); iter.hasNext();){
            String item = (iter.next()).getList(0).stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .map(String::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            sb.append(item).append(",");
        }
        int i = sb.lastIndexOf(",");
        sb.replace(i, i+1, "]");
        System.out.println(sb);
        /**
         * [99896,10,50,30,40]
         */
```

### option-2

```
         Dataset<Row> p = df.withColumn("column",
                expr("concat('[', concat_ws(',', collect_list(concat_ws(',', column))), ']')"));
        for (java.util.Iterator<Row> iter = p.toLocalIterator(); iter.hasNext();){
            String item = (iter.next()).get(0).toString();
            System.out.println(item);
        }
        /**
         * [99896,10,50,30,40]
         */
```

Answer (score 2):

So basically, what you're doing is looping through each row, getting the `WrappedArray` for that row and using `WrappedArray`'s `toString()` method. What you need to do instead of calling `toString()` is to loop over that `WrappedArray` and print each value in it